# Removing "." from number-strings in dataframe using regex deletes all from it

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, dataframe

I have downlaoded data from SAP and trying to do ETL. Data set looks like below.

```
11.780,00
13.824,00
0,00
33.024,00
```

I am trying to remove "dot" first and then replace "comma" with dot
The following code makes the whole column as blank (everything just vanishes) It's just a simple regex replace statement
`sales = sales.withColumn('gross', regexp_replace('gross', '.', ''))`

Again when I try as below
`sales = sales.withColumn('gross', regexp_replace('gross', '.', ':'))`
output looks like below 
`:::::::::::::`

How do I handle this conversion. It's bit weird. Thanks.

Comment: try `sales.withColumn('gross', regexp_replace('gross', '\.', ''))` .In regex `dot` = `any character except new line`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As RahulRauts commented: the `.` is a special character when used in regex. It means "Any single character". You need to escape it by prepending a backslash in front if you mean a literal `'.'`

```
sales = sales.withColumn('gross', regexp_replace('gross', '\.', ''))
```

See https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html:

> **The special characters are:**
>
> `.` (Dot.) In the default mode, this matches any character except a
>   newline.
>
> [...]
>
> `\` Either escapes special characters (permitting you to match
>   characters like '*', '?', and so forth), or signals a special
>   sequence; special sequences are discussed below.

Comment: Thanks. When i try to replace comma to dot, again it's not working.. `sales = sales.withColumn('gross', regexp_replace('gross', ',', '\.'))`

Comment: @lilly remove the \ before the . this time :)